# Determining solubility thresholds

Tags: solubility

Are there any sources that could provide Ksp value thresholds for things that are "completely soluble", "partially soluble", and "not soluble"?

Comment: A $K_{sp}$ value is a parametric measurement but  "completely soluble", "partially soluble", and "not soluble" are non-parametric measurements. So it seems you're asking about apples and oranges. Please clarify. Also note that solubility is significantly dependent on temperature which is another  factor to consider.

Comment: I am looking for some rules of thumb for Ksp values such that if the Ksp is greater than x at 25C, it is refered to as "completely soluble". In my mind, anything with a Ksp value around that of NaCl I would say is "completely soluble".

Comment: Then you already have a rule of thumb - don't expect better rules because they are no strict rules.